# Can I connect an off-the-shelf boost converter and a buck converter end to end?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-current, buck-boost

I have a 9~15 volt source (a battery) that I need to turn into stable 12 volts efficiently. The load (a graphics card) will draw up to 200 watts. Can I just get a boost converter and a buck converter from Aliexpress and connect them end to end? Like, boost to e.g. 24 volts and buck back down to 12. I can't find a single combined component that would do what I want, and building one is probably beyond my skill level.

Comment: Wikipedia says the tolerance is 5%. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply

Comment: Buying something from Aliexpress is a risk unless there is proper documentation and some assurance of a reasonable quality controlled product manufacture.

Comment: You might find that the evaluation boards of suitable buck-boost converters fit your needs.  Linear Technolgy LTC3789 for example is a 12V 1% 12A with 4-38 Vin regulator and has demo boards for it.

Comment: What is the requirement specification for "12 V" *of the graphics card* in question?

Comment: It's a much better idea to buy a buck-boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can connect a boost and a buck converter in series. But this might not be what you want to do.

Each converter will have about 10% of power loss (heat). For your 200W load, this would mean you would have to get rid of about 40W heat!

So it would look much better if you connect 2 batteries in series and use a single buck converter for your application.

Or you could use a sepic converter, which combined buck and boost somehow.